# How can I use custom object sets of a specifc object type as input data in my Palantir Foundry Workshop module

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I want to provide a Workshop module that can be applied to arbitrary object sets (eg. explorations) that are of a specific object type. The arbitrary object set is defined by the user and somehow provided to the Workshop module when the module is opened. Any functionality inside the module is the applied on this user specified object set. I assume that the user knows the rid of his custom object set (ri.object-set.main.versioned-object-set.UUID) and would be able to provide it.

One way in workshop would be promoted variables. But the documentation stats that this is not possible using promoted variables - I can only use a single object (using its RID) as input (https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/state-saving/#unsupported-promoted-variables-types-in-the-url). The documentation suggests that I can recreate the object set somehow using promoted string vars and using them to filter object sets. From my understanding the workaround is only feasible if the object set has a very small number of filter criteria and the criteria reflect direct values. For me its not an option.

**Question**: Are there any other ways in workshop to achieve the goal described above. Either with promoted variables or using a different approach?

Comment: Where is this object set coming from ? Quiver ? Another Workshop ? Object Explorer ? ... There _might_ be easier options than just passing an RID.

Comment: @ZettaP: Die Object sets are custom Explorations that a user creates using Object Explorer (https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/object-explorer/save-explorations/). The only requirement for the user is, that that the objects within the object set are all of one given object type. The user can then use any kind of filtering to create his personal object set. The object set (aka the Exploration) will then have its own RID.
The workshop module should then use this object set.

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer fully your use-case, but you can use [routing](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/routing/) to have variable defined in the URL of Workshop and so initialize them with a given value.

You will open your Workshop with `/workspace/module/view/latest/ri.workshop.main.module.d3e0324a-894f-4f9a-9c65-89cd86ddfb95/page?object-set=ri.object-set.main.object-set.xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx` and this will "set" the value of the `object-set` variable

[image]

Note: This doesn't work with `ri.object-set.main.versioned-object-set...` but works with `ri.object-set.main.object-set...`

Comment: Do you know what is the artefact representation in Foundry that is using rid of the form "ri.object-set.main.object-set..."? The one with "ri.object-set.main.versioned-object-set..." is used by saved Explorations from my understanding.